# Adaptive Runge-Kutta for Stochastic (Projected) Gross-Pitaevskii Equation

Tags: runge-kutta, integration, stochastic, adaptive-timestepping, stochastic-ode

I am using the [XMDS](http://www.xmds.org/) library for solving the stochastic (projected) Gross-Pitaevskii equation

$$i \hbar \partial \Phi\left(\mathbf{r},t\right)_t=\hat{\mathcal{P}}\left\{(1-i \gamma)\left(\hat{H}_{\mathrm{GP}}-\mu\right) \Phi+\eta\left(\mathbf{r},t\right)\right\}$$

where $\eta\left(\mathbf{r},t\right)$ is a stochastic noise field.

In the XMDS documentation, it is noted that:

> As all Runge-Kutta solutions have equal order of convergence for stochastic equations, **if the step-size is limited by the stochastic term then the step-size estimation is entirely unreliable**. Adaptive Runge-Kutta algorithms are therefore not appropriate for stochastic equations.
>   (http://www.xmds.org/reference_elements.html?highlight=adaptive)

I have noted the arguments set out in this SE answer: [Easily understandable argument that normal Runge–Kutta methods cannot be generalised to SDEs?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27514/easily-understandable-argument-that-normal-runge-kutta-methods-cannot-be-general/27676#27676).

From the XMDS documentation, they note that if the step-size $\Delta x$ is limited by $\eta$ then adaptive Runge-Kutta is unreliable. I am unsure what "limited" means in this sense... my step size is (I believe!) independent of the stochastic noise $\eta$ and is instead dependent on some circular momentum cut-off in spectral space.

Furthermore, work by A. Das *et al*. ([Scientific Reports **2**, Article number: 352 (2012)](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep00352#ref-CR50)) explicitly uses adaptive Runge-Kutta methods for solving this stochastic PDE, but they do not explain why this is valid.

Why is it possible to use adaptive Runge-Kutta in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that adaptive step-size methods are appropriate for this equation given it is a Langevin equation in the limit of weak, additive noise. [1]

It should be noted (if anyone were to stumble upon this post), that stochastic differential equations with strong **multiplicative** noise are typically unstable and not appropriate for adaptive step-size methods.

[1] See G. N. Milstein and M. V. Tretyakov's general discussion of SDEs in *Stochastic Numerics for Mathematical Physics*, Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg, pp. 211-283, (2004).

Comment: "It should be noted (if anyone were to stumble upon this post), that stochastic differential equations with strong multiplicative noise are typically unstable and not appropriate for adaptive step-size methods." You can't take a deterministic one and think it would work, but the [adaptivity algorithms for SDEs in DifferentialEquations.jl are made for the strong sense](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5844583/), [multiplicative noise is a form of diagonal noise and is fairly simple](https://docs.sciml.ai/latest/tutorials/sde_example/). Have you given those a try?